# Disable Caching When Reading from Floppy

Tags: java, caching, disk, floppy

**TLDR:**  If you're polling for a floppy on MacOS, use rdisk and *cleanup all handles on that file!*

Good Evening!

I'd like to use some old floppy diskettes as ID cards, so I need to know when one is inserted into my USB reader.  The reader, made by Sony, shows up as a disk drive under Linux and MacOS, which makes me think (correct me if I'm wrong) that I won't be getting a signal from it when I insert the diskette.  So I turned to polling.  I wrote the Java below, which uses the FileReader to poll the raw disk until it can read something and then returns.  I do the same thing  with `inverse = true` to detect when the card is ejected.  The first step works and returns when the disk is inserted.  My problem arises when trying to detect the disk's removal.  Something is caching the data, because when I eject the diskette, `System.out.println(f.read());` keeps printing the charcode of the first character stored on the floppy.  However, when I invoke `head -c 100 /dev/disk2`, it detects the read error properly.  What could possibly be storing the read bytes and how do I force Java to refresh the data directly from the disk?

```
private static void waitDevice(String path, int pollIntervalMS, boolean invert) {
    try {
        while (invert ^ !pollDevice(path)) {
            System.out.println("Waiting...");
            Thread.sleep(pollIntervalMS);
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)  {}
}

private static Boolean pollDevice(String path) {
    try {
        FileReader f = new FileReader(path);
        System.out.println(f.read());
        f.close();
        return true;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is the output of my full program.

**Drive Connected.  No Floppy**

```
Waiting...
37
```

**Drive Connected.  Floppy Inserted.  Read data printed first.**

```
%%Bob%Smith%1534739997363%2fb66e3469de30174ddf9a80386a5cc6810baddd1a1dfea3489cdc8dd78fc81%%
Inserted
37
Waiting...
37
Waiting...
37
```

**Drive Connected.  Floppy Removed**

```
Waiting...
37
Waiting...
37
Waiting...
37
Waiting...
```

**EDIT: 8/20/2018**

I answered my own question.  There were two errors present in my approach.  The first is that I was reading from `/dev/disk2`, which implements caching and not `/dev/rdisk2` which does not.  The second problem was that I was leaving open file handles on the device putting it into an invalid state.  Using try/catch/finally I am now ensuring that my `FileReader` for `/dev/rdisk2` is always closed despite expected IOExceptions.  Here is the revised code.

```
private static void waitDevice(String path, int pollIntervalMS, boolean invert) {
        try {
            while (invert ^ !pollDevice(path)) {
                System.out.println("Waiting...");
                Thread.sleep(pollIntervalMS);
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)  {}
    }

    private static Boolean pollDevice(String path) {
        FileReader f = null;
        try {
            f = new FileReader(path);
            System.out.println(f.read());
            return true;
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if (f != null) {
                try {
                    f.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {System.out.println("Error Closing Device!!!");}
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: I think that I previously achieved this in Python on Linux by disabling the page cache for the device itself with `hdparm -A 0`, but Python would quickly hang making the solution unworkable.